# Symfony 4 - .env Variables Not Available

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, symfony4

I'm running in to a brick wall here. Everything so far with Symfony 4 has been sunshine and daisies but now I can't seem to add any environment variables to my project.

In my project root there is the default `.env` file populated with the usual `APP_ENV`, `APP_SECRET` and `DATABASE_URL`; that's all great. However, adding any custom variable there doesn't seem to actually *do* anything! If I add in `ANOTHER_VAR=hello_world`, for example, and then run `bin/console debug:container --env-vars`, it only dumps the `APP_SECRET` and `DATABASE_URL` variables. If I run `bin/console about`, however, it shows me all of the variables inside `.env`.

I thought it might be a cached variable issue but if I change the value of `APP_SECRET` and run the console command again, it dumps the changed value but still not my custom variables.

I *suspect* that the env vars are not available to the container by default but that doesn't seem right to me (plus it seems somewhat contradictory to what [the Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables) themselves say).

What do I need to do to register these variables so I can access them inside a Controller, for example?

Comment: You might wanna check, so you don't have set `APP_ENV` in the global environment, terminal: `export`, on most systems, or if your in `CMD`: `set`.

Comment: @Anuga, I knew that wasn't an issue because I was able to edit `APP_SECRET` without issue. I managed to figure out my problem eventually, but thanks! (:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is typical of me, I stumble across the answer within half an hour of getting frustrated and asking for help.

Contrary to how the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables) reads, simply adding a variable to the `.env` file does not make it available inside the Container (and so not listed when you run `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` nor available inside a Controller using `$this->getParameter('env(VAR)')`). And thinking about it now, this kinda makes sense because you wouldn't want *all* of your protected variables available to everything that runs from the Container.

In order to access an env var you need to parameterise it first and this way you can limit access to it as well.
Any env vars that you want available to all of your services you can set within the `config/services.yaml` file like so (assuming autowiring is enabled):

```
parameters:
   variable_a: '%env(VAR_A)%'
```

If you would prefer to restrict the env var to just a few services, then you can inject it in to your service as an argument within `config/services.yaml` like so:

```
services:
  App\Service\Foo:
    arguments:
      $bar: '%env(BAZ)%'
```

With the parameter set up like the above, I can now access that env var inside my Controller with `$this->getParameter('variable_a')`. Running `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` also outputs it.

It's a bit of a pain since I assumed that simply calling `$this->getParameter('env(BAZ)')` would do the trick but I suppose it makes sense (there is actually no parameter called `env(BAZ)`).

Hopefully this helps someone else struggling to wrap their head around this.